# Pass Parameters from Grape::API to Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grape-api, serialization

I am getting a parameter e.g: member_id in Grape::API like

```
   desc 'Return Events'
         params do
             requires :member_id, type: Integer, desc: 'Member'
         end
         get 'all' do
              #some code
         end
     end
```

and I want to pass it to `ActiveModel::Serializer` so that I can perform some functionality.

Is there any way that I can pass it to `ActiveModel::Serializer`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you serialize an object using `ActiveModel::Serializers`, you can pass along options which are available inside the serializer as `options` (or `instance_options`, or `context`, [depending on which version of AMS you're using](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/599)).

For instance, in Rails you would pass a `foo` option like so:

```
# 0.8.x or 0.10.x
render @my_model, foo: true
MyModelSerializer.new(@my_model, foo: true).as_json

# 0.9.x
render @my_model, context: { foo: true }
MyModelSerializer.new(@my_model, context: { foo: true }).as_json
```

In your serializer you access `options` (or `instance_options`) to get the value:

```
class MyModelSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :my_attribute

  def my_attribute
    # 0.8.x: options
    # 0.9.x: context
    # 0.10.x: instance_options
    if options[:foo] == true
      "foo was set"
    end
  end
def
```

Comment: in both cases options[:current_family] and  instance_options[:current_family] it says it don't know options or instance_options

Comment: Tricky! Sorry about that - which version of AMS are you on?

Comment: active_model_serializers (0.9.5) and grape-active_model_serializers (1.3.2), actually in gem file I 've just written "grape-active_model_serializers"

Comment: Unfortunately 0.9.x differs substantially from 0.8.x and 0.10.x.  0.9.x requires custom options to be nested under a `context` key, and you use `context` instead of `instance_options` to access them.

Comment: I didn't get it, tried some search about context in serializer  but didn't find something usefull.
can you explain it a little

Comment: I updated the example code in the answer above - try `MyModelSerializer.new(@my_model, context: { foo: true }).as_json` and `if context[:foo] == true` in your serializer.

Comment: @gmcnaughton How do I access the current_user in the serializer? When I do MyModelSerializer.new( it does not let me access the current_user.